# jsfiddle unique identifier generation

Tags: uid

Consider jsfiddle.net:

When you press "save" they generate uid for your jsfiddle like vzBZB.

How do they do it? Why only 5 characters?

And first of all - How do they make sure there's never a collision? (same uid generated for 2 different jsfiddles)

Can they run out of UIDs some day?

Comment: well if it is just letters and it is case sensitive that would give you 3.8E8 IDs. To put that into perspective, they could give out a new ID every second for 12 years

Comment: As for avoiding collisions, I have no idea what that service is, but in theory they could just hand them out sequentially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do they do it? Why only 5 characters?

The only sure way to know is ask jsFiddle, so this part of your question is not really constructive.

The UIDs are not generates sequentially, which is probably to prevent someone from browsing thorugh everybody else's fiddles.

> How do they make sure there's never a collision?

That part is simple: You can just generate one at random and check if it does not exists already.

If it doesn't, you are done. If it does, repeat.

As long as there at least as much unused UIDs as used ones, you don't have to repeat more than once most times.

> Can they run out of UIDs some day?

With a 52 letter alphabet (`A-Z` and `a-z`), you have `52 ^ 5 = 380,204,032` different UIDs available.

That already is a lot of fiddles, but if they ever run out, they could just add a sixth letter.